# Need help redirecting and firing a pixel

Tags: php, redirect

I'm an affiliate marketer with essentially no programming experience, but I need a little help and I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Currently I use a simple PHP redirect so that my advertiser can't see the ref URL of the site I have my ads on. (I assume this accomplishes that?)

```
<?php
header("Location: DESINATION URL");
exit;
?>
```

The ad server that I use allows me to target or exclude my ad campaigns to/from any user that has fired a particular pixel (iframe or script). The idea is that with this re-targeting capability, you can target your ad campaigns to people who visited a particular website in the past that you have a pixel on.

So, what I need to do is not only redirect users, but I want to figure out how to simultaneously fire either the iframe or script pixel. Here's the idea. Someone that clicks on one of my ads but doesn't end up making a purchase isn't someone that I want to serve ads to over and over again. Once they click, I want them to no longer be eligible to see one of my ads. The only way to do this is to fire a pixel for that user when they click, so that I can then use this retargeting feature of the ad server I use to exclude those users from my campaigns. Make sense?

User lands on the page
pixel fires
page redirects to destination URL

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, a header-based redirect will ALWAYS show the url to the client. It's essentially telling the browser "hey, go over here and fetch this address". Your server isn't fetching the contents of that address, it's just telling the browser where to go to fetch it itself.

What you want is a proxy - your server fetches the URL and sends the results back to the client.

And what do you mean, "fired a pixel"? Loading a web bug?

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for getting back to me so quickly. The "firing of a pixel" like I talk about is just the execution of a bit of code. The system I use (sitescout) gives me two options, iframe and script. Here are both: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pixel.sitescout.com/ap/a9bf8ea5f56101e0"></script>                             <iframe src="http://pixel.sitescout.com/ap/a9bf8ea5f56101e0?if=1" width="0" height="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: Sorry, having trouble getting it to show properly. I'm pretty much open to all ideas and would consider hiring someone to help me set this up. The firing of that pixel writes something to the user's cookie, which the ad server then sees at the moment it goes to serve an ad to that user, thus giving the ad server the ability to target or exclude that user based on the cookie contents. I think I'm making this sound more complicated than it is, but I do appreciate any help.